# How to delete an record from array of active record result in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to delete one entry from an array of active record query result.
So I used following code :

```
<%match_results_comfirmation=MatchResult.where("challenge_id IN (?)",chllenges_ids)%>
<%match_results_comfirmation_loop.each do|j|%>
<%match_results_comfirmation=match_results_comfirmation.delete_at(0)%>
<%end%>
```

This is giving an error :
undefined method `delete_at' for #< MatchResult:0x00000003a73a48>

Then I used:

```
<%match_results_comfirmation=MatchResult.where("challenge_id IN (?)",chllenges_ids)%>
<%match_results_comfirmation_loop.each do|j|%>
<%match_results_comfirmation=match_results_comfirmation.delete(j)%>
<%end%>
```

But then it is giving an error :
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of delete use drop :

```
<%match_results_comfirmation=match_results_comfirmation.drop(1)%>
```

Here 1 indicates 1st record.